# Angular dropdown menu

Tags: html, angular.js

I've made a dropdown menu using angularJS, it works fine but I feel that I'm not following the DRY principle. Is there a way to combine this switch statement into something more efficient with less code? Instead of having 3 "cases" can I just use an OR operator inside of a `data-ng-switch-when` or something like that? This code will get bigger because it's quite a big project so code efficiency is key.

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in mainMenu" data-ng-switch on="item"><a href="{{item}}.php">{{item}}</a>

        <ul data-ng-switch-when="Meddelanden">
            <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in subMenu.messages"><a href="{{subitem}}.php">{{subitem}}</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul data-ng-switch-when="Mina sidor">
            <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in subMenu.myPages"><a href="{{subitem}}.php">{{subitem}}</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul data-ng-switch-when="Verktyg">
            <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in subMenu.tools"><a href="{{subitem}}.php">{{subitem}}</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's my controller containing the menu items:

```
onlinePlatform.controller('onlinePlatformCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.mainMenu = ['Startsida', 'Nyheter', 'Meddelanden', 'Mina sidor', 'Forum', 'Kalender', 'Verktyg', 'Hjälp'],
    $scope.subMenu = {
        messages: ['Inkorg', 'Skickat', 'Borttaget'],
        myPages: ['Mina kurser', 'Mitt schema', 'Klasslista', 'Anteckningar'],
        tools: ['Ladda ner Dreamspark produkter']
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your menus more uniform, then you won't have to do the `ng-switch`-ing.  So something like

```
$scope.menus = [
  {
    title: 'Startsida'
  },
  {
    title: 'Messages',
    items: ['Inkorg', ...]
  },
  {
    title: 'My Pages',
    items: ['Mina kurser', ...]
  },
  ...
];
```

Then check whether you have the `items` field and if so, render the items:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="menu in menus"><a href="{{menu.title}}.php">{{menu.title}}</a>
        <ul ng-if="menu.items">
            <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in menu.items"><a href="{{subitem}}.php">{{subitem}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It might be worthwhile to split the URLs from the titles as well.

This approach will break down somewhat at a point when the nesting level of your menu gets too deep, because you have to add more nested lists, but until then this will keep working.

Comment: So in the HTML I would write isExist="items"? instead of the switch thing?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated with a sketch which should work.

Comment: This works fantastic, thank you so much lad! Will be a lot easier to structure the entire thing now :)

Comment: Great tip about the URL thing also, that concerned me a bit as well. This approach also allows me to solve an annoying bug which occurred in the Jquery.